# Improper Integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right) dx$

Tags: trigonometry, improper-integrals

I need to calculate this improper integral. 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right) dx$$
 How do I prove that $$ \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right) $$ has an asymptotic equivalence with: $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$

And by the p-test that it diverges?

Comment: Please improve your question: Your integral is not indefinite. It seems that you use $x$ with to different meanings.

Comment: There seemed to be a typo in my title and integral, x is replaced by 1 now and by indefinite I meant improper. Sorry, English isn't my native language

Comment: Since the integral does not depend on x, it makes no sense to ask wether it looks
like $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x\rightarrow \infty.\;$ Do you mean something like this:
$$\int_{x}^{\infty} \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{t}+1} \right) \right) dt$$

Comment: I'm trying to ask if the function $$ \sin( \sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt(x) + 1} ) ) $$ has asymptotic equivalence with $ x -> \infty $

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an asymptotic equivalence. Since for any $y\in[0,\pi/2]$ 
$$\sin y\geq\frac{2y}{\pi}$$
holds by convexity,
$$\int_{N}^{+\infty}\sin\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\,dx \geq \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{N}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}+1}$$
holds for any $N$ big enough, hence the starting is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as $x\rightarrow \infty\;$ you have the asmptotic relations
$$\sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right)
\sim \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \right)
\sim  \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} \right)
\sim  \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} 
$$
because for small $z\rightarrow 0\;$ you have $\sin(z) \sim z;\;$and therefore the integral 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right) dx$$ diverges. You can get some better estimate with a CAS e.g.

$$\sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right) =
\sqrt\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: How can you prove your first equivalent ? I think the way is to write : $\sin \left( \sin\left( \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \right) \right)
\sim  \sin\left( \frac {1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \right)
\sim  \frac {1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \sim \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Seems no great difference to **your** first step (at least for the simple estimate), both use the composition of continous functions.

Comment: You cannot (in general) compose equivalent.